# Checkboxes are not checked

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I cannot get DB values of games to be selected:

```
Game:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true, unsigned: true }
    game_name: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    logo: { type: string(100), notnull: true, comment: "Game Logo" }
  indexes:
    it:
      fields: game_name
      type: unique

Campaign:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true, unsigned: true }
    name: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    percentage: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
    is_active: { type: integer(1), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
    start: { type: datetime, notnull: true }
    end: { type: datetime, notnull: true }

CampaignGames:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true, unsigned: true }
    campaign_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
    game_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
  indexes:
    tc:
      fields: [campaign_id, game_id]
      type: unique
  relations:
    Campaign: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: campaign_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: CampaignCampaignGames }
    Game: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: game_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: GameCampaignGames }
```

I have added games checkbox here which belongs to Game model to let the user add games to CampaignGames, but unfortunately they never checked... And these values are present in DB.

```
class AdminconsoleCampaignForm extends CampaignForm
{

public function configure()
{
    parent::configure();

    $this->widgetSchema['is_active'] = new sfWidgetFormSelectRadio(array(
        'choices' => array(1 => 'On', 0 => 'Off'),
    ));

    $games = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Game')->getGames();

    $this->widgetSchema['game_id'] = new sfWidgetFormSelectCheckbox(array(
        'choices' => $games
    ));

    $this->validatorSchema['game_id'] = new sfValidatorChoice(array(
        'choices' => array_keys($games)
        , 'multiple' => true
        , 'required' => false
    ));

    $this->removeFields();

}
```

Also tried to use

```
$this->widgetSchema['game_id']->setDefault(array($data));
```

No luck. How to resolve it? I'm really stuck on that.

Comment: So is your main problem, that you're trying to make an n-to-m relation between Game and Campaign? If so, the question's title might be confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things that caught my attention:

### 1. You're not using Doctrine's `boolean` data type

Try changing your `schema.yml` to the following:

```
Campaign:
  [...]
  columns:
    [...]
    is_active:
      type: boolean
      notnull: true
      default: 0 # Or whichever default value you prefer
    [...]
```

This way Symfony/Doctrine will take care of anything regarding the `is_active` row of your `Campaign` record.

If you now rebuild your model your `BaseCampaignForm.class.php` will define the `is_active` widget automatically like this:

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
  [...]
  'is_active' => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(),
  [...]
);

$this->setValidators(array(
  [...]
  'ist_active' => new sfValidatorBoolean(array('required' => false)),
  [...]
);
```

*Note:* That `required` is set to `false` is there because if a checkbox isn't selected it's not posted either. The `sfValidatorBoolean` takes care of this and disables the value all by itself. If you would set it to true than the user wouldn't be able to uncheck the box and submit the form without a validator exception.

### 2. You tried to set form object defaults in its form's widget

In your code you used:

```
$this->widgetSchema['game_id']->setDefault(array($data));
```

This won't work because you're using a Form with an object attached to it (a `BaseFormDoctrine`). All the default values are taken right out of the object assigned to that form (in your case a `Campaign` object because you're extending `CampaignForm`).

**(Major pitfall) If you want to set default values on a form object you have to set them on the form object itself :**

```
$this->getObject()->setGameId($id);
```

Default object values can't be set using the object form's widgets. These default values will always be overwritten by the actual object values (which makes sense because the form represents the object).

Glad if I was able to help you in some way.

Comment: Ok, I have changed the schema, but still need to set $this->widgetSchema['is_active'] because only one option without label is shown.

Answer (score 1):

If your choices are based on doctrine records (which they are), then you should use [`sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice). Change the renderer_class option if you want to get radio buttons / checkboxes instead of a select tag.

Comment: How do I add validator with 'choices' options if I use sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice?

Comment: You should use [`sfValidatorDoctrineChoice`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfValidatorDoctrineChoice) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$game` array probably has the keys by order (0,1,2,3,4) and you end up having a select like:

```
<select>
  <option value="0">Option 1</option>
  <option value="1">Option 2</option>
  <option value="2">Option 3</option>    
</select>
```

But your object ids do not coincide with those keys.
You have to change the line:

```
$games = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Game')->getGames();
```

to:

```
$c = Doctrine::getTable('Game');
$c->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_COLL_KEY, 'id');
$games = $c->getGames();
```

so that the arrays gets the keys = ids. Like:

```
<select>
  <option value="3">Option 1</option>
  <option value="7">Option 2</option>
  <option value="9">Option 3</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: No, I took it into account of course. This is how I do it:
    public static function getGames()
    {
        $return = Doctrine_Core::getTable('MainGame')->findAll(Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
        
        $arr = array();
        
        foreach($return as $game)
         $arr[$game['id']] = $game['game_name'];
         
        return $arr;
        
    }
Are you sure that would work? getGames() is the method defined in models...

Comment: Is it possible to set ATTR_COLL_KEY attribute for select()? I don't want to pull all the fields...

Comment: Yes you can. just use the setAttribute above and then create your query: `$games = $c->select('id')->findAll(Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY)`